# eclipse debugger: attaching source-code of maven dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, maven-2

I'd like to use the source code of maven-managed dependencies when debugging our webapp in myEclipse 8.

I have managed to attach the sources to the libraries in the "Maven Managed Dependencies" classpath container, i.e. when I open a class file from a dependency (e.g. using Ctrl-Shift-T), I see the source code.

However, when I define a server connector for my tomcat, deploy the wepapp to it, and launch it in debug mode and execution halts on a breakpoint in that same class, the editor pane only displays the text "source not found", and a button to edit the "source lookup path". I have attempted to manually add the "Maven Managed Dependencies" classpath container, only to be told "Use maven project settings to configure depedency resolution". However, I see no useful setting in that property pane ...

How can I attach those sources? I am aware that this works with the m2e plugin and wtp, but I'd rather avoid convincing the rest of my team to switch plugins ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since discovered that this problem only occurs if the server is launched using a launch configuration.

The problem does not occur if the server is started by:

1. click the server icon in the toolbar -> context menu appears
2. mouse over the intended server -> submenu appears
3. click on "Start"

While this precludes sharing the server configuration by checking the launch configuration into version control, it at least allows seamless debugging.

Answer (score 10):

Looks like [issue **MNGECLIPSE-983**](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-983)

> I have confirmed that if I manually pick the External Archive option and find the relevant -sources jar (navigating that big `.m2/repository` tree to find it) and then add the jar as a sources it does work, and surprisingly it does remember the next time which isn't too bad.
>   That's at least doable I think for me because we don't often need to step debug through external dependencies, but when we do, it's often frequent, so adding it once while a bit of a pain, can be done on a case by case basis.

Comment: +1 for the link. However, the workaround is quite cumbersome, since we check in the project to version control, and not all devs have their maven repo in the same place. I am therefore still looking for a better solution.

Comment: I think it should be possible to use a variable in the eclipse configuration for the location of the local repository. So each developer would just have to set that variable.

Comment: adding jar using add external archive option didn't work for me.Any specific reason?

Comment: @vis 7 years later, I am not sure. Maybe asking a new question would be best here?

Answer (score 1):

Please do the following steps in Eclipse IDE(Tested with Version: 3.5.2),

1. In Package Explorer, Right Click on the Project which integrated with Maven container.
2. Select Maven 2 and then select "Fetch Source JARs".
   The above action wil fetch sources of all the 3rd party jars present in the Maven Classpath.

Regards,
Rajesh.

Comment: If dependecies have changed, the "source not found" error might appear again. Just click on "edit source lookup path" and immediately on "OK" (should search again in all dependencies).

Answer (score -4):

Just put the .m2/repository/ folder itself with the search subfolders option.