# Maven tomcat plugin does not allow stepping into dependent jars

Tags: eclipse, debugging, maven, tomcat

I am using the Maven Tomcat plugin to test a Maven webservice project using Hibernate.

My POM looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.honeywell.gt</groupId>
    <artifactId>WSOCCMeoReports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Simple CXF project using spring configuration</name>
    <description>Simple CXF project using spring configuration</description>

    <properties>
        <shiro.version>1.2.1</shiro.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>                      
        <cxf.version>2.6.1</cxf.version>                        
        <hibernate.version>3.6.5.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>    
       <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>                          

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>                   
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
          <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
          <version>${shiro.version}</version>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sybase.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>SybDriver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>                                                       

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <!-- mvn clean install tomcat:run-war to deploy
                    Look for "Running war on http://xxx" and
                    "Setting the server's publish address to be /yyy"
                    in console output; WSDL browser address will be
                    concatenation of the two: http://xxx/yyy?wsdl
                    -->
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>start-tomcat</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run-war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <port>${test.server.port}</port>
                                <path>/webservice</path>
                                <fork>true</fork>
                                <useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>true</useSeparateTomcatClassLoader>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectNameTemplate>[artifactId]-[version]</projectNameTemplate>
                        <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
                        <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

The Debug goals are `tomcat:run-war`

After hitting a break point in the service I cannot step into third party dependencies such as Hibernate.  However, if I run a Unit test from the same Maven web service project, I can step into Hibernate.

EDIT 1:

I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808651/eclipse-debugger-attaching-source-code-of-maven-dependencies) and got some ideas about attaching source.  Matter of fact, I am trying to debug Hibernate, so I edited source lookup and added paths to the following external archives in my .m2 repository:

```
hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.5.Final
hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.
```

Saved changes and Eclipse still cannot find source to step into.  Anyone out there?

Comment: Why the votes for closure?  it is indeed a legitimate question no?

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to be a know issue with Maven Plugin for Eclipse as indicated [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-983).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808651/eclipse-debugger-attaching-source-code-of-maven-dependencies?lq=1) was helpful but I found out that for hibernate 3.6.5, I had to add hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final-sources.jar to source lookup path instead of hibernate-core-3.6.5.Final.jar.